# Is event.currentTarget always equal to $(this) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this phrase always true?

```
$("p").click(function(event) {
  alert( event.currentTarget === this ); 
});
```

Is one method preferred over the other? I like to use `$(this)` instead of  `event.currentTarget` but can one do better in some conditions? Which is better? Are absolutely the same?

And another nuance - When checking on firebug `console.log(this)` and `console.log($(this))` gives me exactly the same element. If they are the same - what is different? (since I know I can write this `$(this).css('color','white')` but can't write `this.css('color','white')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally, yes, it will be the same.  You can make it different by using [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) to manipulate the context, but in practice you probably never will.

```
$(document.body).on('click', $.proxy(function(e) {
    console.log(this);            // window
    console.log(e.currentTarget); // document.body
}, window));
```

As to the other question, `this` is a native DOM element, whereas `$(this)` is a jQuery object wrapping that DOM element. The jQuery wrapper means you can run jQuery functions such as `css`, which are not available on native DOM elements.

---

And, to answer the precise wording of your question, `event.currentTarget` is normally equal to `this`, not to `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your answer is above. I hope its clear enough.

No `console.log(this)` and `console.log($j(this))` will not give you the same result. $(this) converts this to a jQuery Object and hence you can call .css like methods which can be called on jQuery objects($(this)) and not the HTML elements which will be `this`.

Answer (score 0):

This property will typically be equal to the this of the function.

If you are using jQuery.proxy or another form of scope manipulation, this will be equal to whatever context you have provided, not event.currentTarget