# How to get event.target of anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `event.target` of clicked link. I have wrapped one of the anchor tags around an image like this:

```js
$("a").click(function(event) {
  alert(event.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#link1">link 1</a>
<br/>
<a href="#link2">
  <img src="http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Despicable-Me-Minions-014.jpg">
</a> <!-- anchor tag wrapped around img -->
```

Here, in case of "link 1" (when it's clicked), I get the desired value (i.e. `"http://stacksnippets.net/js#link1"`). But, in case of the image (when it's clicked), I'm getting "Object HTMLImageElement". How can I get the value `"http://stacksnippets.net/js#link2"` when the image is clicked?

**EDIT:**

I need to get `"http://stacksnippets.net/js#link2"` when the image is clicked, analogous to `"http://stacksnippets.net/js#link1"` in case of "link1".

Comment: Can't a person ask a simple question here? Why do you downvote without giving a reason?

Comment: this is **too** simple a question ... your stated goals are conflicting. i'm sure you find it easy because the complete question is inside your brain, but the wording used does not describe the problem well.

Comment: FYI.. too simple a question !== Wrong question
The best part is that you find it *too* simple and "not described well" at the same time! :D. Have a great day ahead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `this` to always get the anchor, as that's the element targeted in the event handler. `event.target` gets the element that initiated the event, in this case the image

```
$("a").click(function() {
    console.log( this );
});
```

Sidenote: `alert` is not a debugging tool !

Comment: Thank you for helping out. :)

I know, but isn't it more handy than console.log? You get to see the output as a prompt. What's the harm? (P.S.: I'm a newbie.)

Comment: @theScorpion Try console logging you event : `console.log(event)`. You could have answered your question with that. `alert` would not.

Comment: @theScorpion - `alert` seems more handy, and most newbies start there, but once you get used to the console, and how you can actually see the data other than just alerting strings, you'll understand why it's invaluable.

Comment: @theScorpion: It also blocks the browser completely, which can have undesired side effects when debugging asynchronous processes.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes! You're right.

Answer (score 6):

As alternative to `this`, you can use [**`event.currentTarget`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget):

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Comment: Is there any reason why you should *want* to do this, however?

Comment: @lonesomeday: `this` might be bound to a different value. Or you using IE and `attachEvent` (which doesn't set `this` to the element). Not sure it it supports `currentTarget` either though ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Ah yes, binding would make them different. Ironically, [this did actually occur to me some time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8604058/417562). Should have remembered!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1fag5586/) is a working example for your request usig JSFiddle.